# Custom email from address using Laravel Mail not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I am trying to send an email with custom "from" address on each email template. I already null the value of "from address" in config/mail but still using the last setup of from address. See code below for config mail

```
'from' => [
    'address' => null,
    'name' => null,
```

I also run

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

but still not working, still doing the default address the I input

This is the email template build file

```
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('customemail@gmail.com')
                    ->subject('London Foster Realty Property Listing')
                    ->view('emails.agent-new-listing', 
                        // array('mls_id' => $this->mlsid)
                    );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `config/mail.php` the `form` is an **array**, so you need to define it as an **array** instead of **string**, change :

```
from('customemail@gmail.com')
```

to,

```
from(['address' => 'customemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Example'])
```

Comment: Already update my email still the previous email is the one sending emails. I did config clear, composer update, and composer dump-autoload still not working

Answer (score 0):

Laravel actually cache's resource views and to send the mail it's using the cached file in your case. Please clear the views cache by running the following command:

```
php artisan view:clear
```